# Hybrid library vs normal one

Tags: library, orcad

We use Orcad and we want to update our libraries. When we place a part and want to rotate it,we don't like the layout of the labels(names,values etc) and thus have to manually reposition them. It's not a big deal but it gets annoying after a while.

To solve this issue, we came with two solutions:

-Create for one component two parts(an horizontal and a vertical one)

-Create a symbol with the convert option which allows us to choose in a click

Does anyone here have any suggestion on what would be best ? I'm leaning towards the convert option because it seems faster and we have less components, but my supervisor would like to know what people in the industry do. I've linked some images to clarify what I mean.
Thank you very much, and even if you don't use Orcad,if you have an informed opinion, I would still like to hear it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ICe.jpg

Comment: I can't visualize what the problem is that you have.

Comment: @Andyaka It's more about what would be best, did you mean you do not understand the initial problem or the difference between the 2 solutions ?

Comment: I've edited the image in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just drag the labels around manually when I draw my schematic. Having something more automated might be nice to help enforce some consistency, especially if you have multiple designers on your team.

I wouldn't make two symbols for the same part, though because if you want to change some part properties down the road sometime, then you'll have to change it in two places.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't really see an advantage of having two symbols over a custom one, it's just asking for trouble

Comment: Having labels of the various params means you must position the labels so a 90 degree flip still keeps them from overlaying each other. But I bet you already knew that.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  yes, the problem is that the rotation tend to put labels in places we don't them to be in. It's just it would be more convenient to have both options with ease, it's absolutely not necessary but it's a nice thing to have plus I'm an intern :p